# Prevent select box from changing

Tags: html, angular

I'm working on an angular js 2 project and I need to create a dropdown (kinda like a link) wherein if you select an option it will trigger an onchange event and redirect the user. Currently I have this:

```
<select id = "dashboard" onchange="goToPage()" class="form-control">
  <option value="" selected disabled>{{ 'Create' | translate }}</option>
  <option value="Applicant" >{{ "dashboard.applicant" | translate}}</option>
  <option value="Reports">{{ "dashboard.report" | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

In the select box I want the 'Create' option to always be selected even if the applicant selects Applicant or Reports. How can I do this behavior?

Comment: Just a quick tip, Angular 2 and AngularJS are two different things, don't mix them by using Angular JS 2. Try changing the tags for a better answer!

Comment: ah yes. I didn't realize angularjs tag is for AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cast `onchange` if user can't change selected value at all, but you can place inside your function this line `document.getElementById("dashboard").selectedIndex = 0;` which will select first option again:

```js
function goToPage(){
document.getElementById("dashboard").selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

```html
<select id = "dashboard" onchange="goToPage()" class="form-control">
  <option value="" selected disabled>{{ 'Create' | translate }}</option>
  <option value="Applicant" >{{ "dashboard.applicant" | translate}}</option>
  <option value="Reports" >{{ "dashboard.report" | translate}}</option>
</select>
```